# Relationship between independent random variables defined over same probability space

Tags: probability, random-variables, intuition, independence

I might misuse some terms. I'd appreciate corrections. I'll try my best to provide a good explanation of what I am trying to ask.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid random variables in that space. My question is: what does it mean for $X$ and $Y$ to be independent in terms of the original space? For instance, if they are independent, does that mean that there is no $g$, such that $Y=g(X)$? I know that indepedence grants $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ and intuitively it means that $X$ carries zero information about $Y$. But going back to the definition of a probability space, what can else can be said?

Comment: Independence of $X$ and $Y$ is defined by $P(X \in A, Y \in B) = P(X \in A) P(Y \in B)$ holding for any Borel subsets $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. You can translate this into some statement on the original probability space by considering the sigma algebras generated by $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Don't get hung up over probability space.  In general when looking at random variables, all are defined on the same space.